# nslookup returns a non-existing hostname

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

I have a small network with a domain controller running Windows 2012 R2. I have servers and other computers/services I needed in place configured in a range "A" of IPs that are not part of any scope in DHCP server. I need to configure a new server in that IP address range ("A") and I had a specific IP address thought for it that I am not using. However, when I run nslookup for that specific ip address, it returns a hostname of an old computer we used to have before !! !
If instead I run nslookup for that hostname, it cannot find the ip back ( the command returns a "can't find computername.domainname.loc"). There is no record in DNS table for that hostname, neither it shows anywhere in DHCP  (as it shouldn't).
I checked my host file and there is not an entry for that address there. If I run an ip scanner (i.e. angry ip scanner), it returns empty for the specific address.
I also went to another computer in the network and ran the same commands (for the ip and then for the hostname) and the results were identical. 
Any ideas how this come to be?
Thanks !!!

Comment: local host file?  wins name? (i.e. computer name)

Answer (score 1):

When you do an nslookup for an ip address, the DNS server does not return A records, it returns PTR records. So please check whether the DNS server still has a PTR record for this IP address.

Edit:  to be more precise when you nslookup 1.2.3.4 then this actually results in a DNS request for 4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa so in this example you may need to check the DNS zone for 3.2.1.in-addr.arpa for an entry (of type PTR) named "4".

Comment: Thank you hertitu. You hit it right in the head. I looked for the ptr record and there it was. Deleted and problem gone. Aren't those records suppose to update ?

Comment: If it was originally added thru DDNS then yes I believe it should have been removed automatically. But if it was created manually then it needs to be deleted manually. Anyway glad to hear it is resolved :)

Comment: The record was not added manually so it was not suppose to be there. Anyway that is a whole new issue. Again thank you for your help.